# How to hide last divider in list of comments using CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, html, divider

I want to hide last divider between comments using css. Code is below.

```
<div id="question_comments" class="comments_container">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment_details">
      <div>
        <p>Comment1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr-comment"></div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="comment_details">
      <div>
        <p>Comment2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hr-comment"></div>
  <div id="question_comment">
    <form> ... </form>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I am generating that in rails view:

```
<div id="question_comments" class="comments_container">
  <% @question.comments.order("created_at ASC").each do |comment| %>
    <%= render :partial => "questions/comment", :locals => { :comment => comment } %>
    <div class="hr-comment"></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render :partial => 'new_comment', :locals => {:targit => @question, :answer => nil} %>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I tried that:

```
div.hr-comment {
  background:url(hr-background.gif) repeat-x;width:100%;height:2px;margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px;width:310px;
}

.hr-comment:last-child { 
    display: none 
}
```

Goal is how to do that without using ruby in view.

Comment: jQuery might be an more reliable way of doing this

Comment: @DerekOrgan not if you want to keep it a CSS-only solution

Comment: @BryanH maybe but are you sure a CSS-only solution will work in all browsers? if so fine

Comment: `div.comment:last-child` does not select anything, because a div with the class `.comment` is never the last child

Comment: I would disagree with the JavaScript solution. You may add it for browsers that don't support the `last-child` pseudo class using something like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com). Maybe the OP's use case is only within a browser that supports those things. I would say, as long as you can do it using CSS, use CSS.

Comment: I added more information about what I want to achieve.

Comment: @DerekOrgan No, I'm guessing that CSS will probably fail in IE (any version) and definitely in IE6 and previous. If you want to style your pages using Javascript, that's cool.

Comment: @BryanH CSS all the way but if it fails in IE then you have no choice but to use an alternative way of achieving the same goal. In this case I'd create a last-child CSS selector and use Ruby to apply it to the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally frowned upon to add extra markup like empty divs purely for styling purposes.

```
.comment + .comment:before {
    border-top:1px solid;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pVcrV/1/

The adjacent selector has greater support in older browsers than pseudo classes like `:last-child` (not available in IE8) or `:last-of-type`.  The `:before` psuedo class has fairly decent support (not available IE7).

Answer (score 4):

The :last-child pseudoclass still cannot be reliably used across browsers. In particular, Internet Explorer versions < 9, and Safari < 3.2 definitely don't support it, although Internet Explorer 7 and Safari 3.2 do support :first-child, curiously.

Your best bet is to explicitly add a last-child (or similar) class to that item, and apply div.last-child instead.

or you could use some Javascript.

Comment: Adding a last-child class as a "go to" technique is wrong. Take float-left `<li>` navigation menus for example...The easiest way our brains think is to use `li{margin:right##px}` then remove the margin from the last `<li>`. It's bad design. Easy, but wrong. Instead, use `li { margin-left:#px }` and then `li:first-child { margin-left:0 }`. Here's the advantages: 1) same effect, 2) backward compatibility, 3) no `.last-child` class crap, and 4) no need for JavaScript. Not trying to offend, `.last` "grinds" me just like adding classes to every element, and never targeting the elements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

How about rethinking the design, and hiding the supported `:first-child` pseudo...and clearing up the div-itus?

```
.comment { border-top:1px solid red }
.comment:first-child { border:none; }​

<div id="question_comments" class="comments_container">
  <div class="comment">
      <p>Comment1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
      <p>Comment2</p>
  </div>
</div>​
```

I realize you may just be using `hr...` as a dumby class, but I took the liberty of using it as a `<hr>` element (which, btw is better than a `<div>` that acts/works the same)

http://jsfiddle.net/pVcrV/

**EDIT: (to put back a container) **

```
<div id="question_comments" class="comments_container">
  <hr>
  <div class="comment">
      <p>Comment1</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="comment">
  ...
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VJVxt/

I'm sort of assuming that you're pulling these comments from a database, and having a server-side language spit out the HTML on the fly. Starting that dump with the divider (then using `:first-child` to hide it) isn't 100% semantic; HOWEVER, one element vs a JavaScript, or a CSS hack seems more than a fair trade-off.

Comment: Looks cool but I want to style that divider ex: I want change width to be max 300px

Comment: @regedarek - You can still do that with the proper element (ie - not a `<div>`). `<hr>`s are fully stylable. You may even also be able to play around with the `overflow` property and still use Dawson's HTML structure (though some might consider that hackish).

Comment: And actually, if you use `<hr>`, you can probably leverage `first-of-type` or `last-of-type`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#question_comments .hr-comment:last-child {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#question_comments > .hr-comment:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```